# Using Flex-Layout with Angular-Universal

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-universal

I'm working in a website using Angular2 + Angular-Universal + Angular-Material.

I have used [universal-starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) to start with my project. I have added Angular-Material and this work fine. Now I need use Flex-Layout, so I have put this dependency in node.module.ts and browser.module.ts. When I try to start server I'm getting this error:

> C:\Users\ivan\Documents\Workspace\Proyectos\cityrep\cityss-front\dist\server\index.js:41207
>               var paramTypes = ctorParameters.map(function (ctorParam) { return ctorParam && ctorParam.type; });
>
> TypeError: ctorParameters.map is not a function
>       at ReflectionCapabilities.parameters (C:\Users\ivan\Documents\Workspace\Proyectos\cityrep\cityss-front\dist\server\index.js:41207:45)
>       at Reflector.parameters (C:\Users\ivan\Documents\Workspace\Proyectos\cityrep\cityss-front\dist\server\index.js:41341:44)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.getDependenciesMetadata (C:\Users\ivan\Documents\Workspace\Proyectos\cityrep\cityss-front\dist\server\index.js:22579:54)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.getTypeMetadata (C:\Users\ivan\Documents\Workspace\Proyectos\cityrep\cityss-front\dist\server\index.js:22544:26)
>       at C:\Users\ivan\Documents\Workspace\Proyectos\cityrep\cityss-front\dist\server\index.js:22687:41
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.getProvidersMetadata (C:\Users\ivan\Documents\Workspace\Proyectos\cityrep\cityss-front\dist\server\index.js:22667:19)
>       at C:\Users\ivan\Documents\Workspace\Proyectos\cityrep\cityss-front\dist\server\index.js:22365:71
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (C:\Users\ivan\Documents\Workspace\Proyectos\cityrep\cityss-front\dist\server\index.js:22356:44)

Somebody knows what could be happening?

Thanks!
Iván

Comment: Seems flex-layout does not yet support Universal https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/187#issuecomment-281204117